# WCF memory leaks on large file transfer

Tags: wcf, memory, file-transfer

My WCF service transfers large files (200Mo), and I see memory usage growing up constantly (1Go, 2Go ... 8Go). Here is what the memory visual studio snapshot gives :

```
Object                      Number    Size (Bytes)
BufferManagerOutputStream   3         266 668 448
...
```

And here, the service configuration :

```
BasicHttpBinding httpb = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
httpb.MaxBufferPoolSize = 0;
```

Have you got any idea for investigation and resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

For the large file transfer between the server and the client, we use the MTOM encoding to reduce the overhead. you could also implement the IDisposable interface on your service contract to manage your memory.
I don’t think the memory leaks due to the fact that WCF I/O transfer. I suggest you could the VS2017 diagnostic tool check where the data object increased.
 [image]
You could refer to the following document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2017

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/